# Why is my filter not intercepting my wp query?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the plugin Code Snippets and Advance Custom Fields. I'm using a code snippet with a WP_QUERY to get posts from the database. I'm trying to get a value from a repeater field. This is not my project so I can't really change the repeater field. So I'll have to deal with. This is the query.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => $limit,
    'post_type'     => 'opleidingen',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'suppress_filters' => 'false',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'     => 'data_$_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
    ),
    'order' => $order,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What I am trying to do is do a comparison with a the date of today with data_$_startdatum where startdatum is a subfield. I've read here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/ that this is the way to do a where comparison on a subfield. But if I run the query I get back 0 posts.

I've tested if the query works by replacing the $ with a 0 and that works. But only for the first index of the repeater field. If I use a OR operator and add in arrays with data_0_startdatum to data_10_startdatum it works for the first 10 indexes. So like this

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => $limit,
    'post_type'     => 'opleidingen',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'suppress_filters' => 'false',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
         array(
            'key'     => 'data_0_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_1_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_2_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_3_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_4_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_5_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_6_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_7_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_8_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'data_9_startdatum',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>',
        )
    ),
    'order' => $order,
);
```

But I would like it to work for the entire array length. Since Wordpress 4.8.3 you can't use the % and you'll have to use a post_where filter to replace % with LIKE. I tried doing this by implementing the following code in my functions.php

```
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    echo($where);
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'data_$", "meta_key LIKE 'data_%", $where);
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
```

This did not work. So I tried to make a snippet with the code snippets plugin and give it a high priority and this also did not work. I also tried to give it a low priorit and this did also not work. I put a echo in the filter and get back the following when viewing the post in the browser

```
AND (wp_posts.ID = '610') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpmm_theme' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_author = 6 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (wp_posts.ID = '610') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_posts.ID = '610') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page'
```

My query is not in there? I get this result when I put the filter in my functions.php or in a seperate snippet with high or low priority.

Answer (score 0):

It would be way better to compose the WP_Query() dynamically. Modifying the where clause on the fly with str_replace is a bad practice and may easily cause bugs.

Try the following:

```
$nrOfFieldsToCheck = 20; // Find the number of fields to check or use a constant
$buf = ['relation' => 'OR'];

// Compose the array of conditions
for($i=0;$i < $nrOfFieldsToCheck; $i++)
{
   $buf[] = [
        'key'     => sprintf('data_%d_startdatum',$i),
        'value'   => $today,
        'compare' => '>'
   ];
}

$args = [
    'numberposts'   => $limit,
    'post_type'     => 'opleidingen',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'suppress_filters' => 'false',
    'meta_query' => $buf,
    'order' => $order
];
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Furthermore, I am not aware that str_replace supports the use of wildcards. Your filter isn't working because it does not find the $needle in the $haystack string value.